# Display fullname of JCheckBox item

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, jcheckbox

I had design a `JFrame` with some components.  In that `JCheckBox` component I had given a name but the full name is not displayed when I run the application.  I want display the given name.

### Code

```
 public class FindDemo extends JFrame
 {
 Label l1;
 JCheckBox matchCase,MatchWholeWords;
 TextField tf;
 JButton find_next,cancel;
 public FindDemo()
 {
    l1 = new Label("Find What: ");
    matchCase=new JCheckBox();
    matchCase.setText("Match Case ");
    MatchWholeWords=new JCheckBox("Match Whole Words ");
    tf = new TextField(30);
    find_next = new JButton("Find Next");
    cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

    setLayout(null);
    int label_w = 80;
    int label_h = 20;
    int tf_w    = 120;

    l1.setBounds(10,10, label_w, label_h);
    add(l1);
    tf.setBounds(10+label_w, 10, tf_w, 20);
    add(tf);
    
    matchCase.setBounds(10, 10+label_h+10, label_w, label_h);
    add(matchCase);
    MatchWholeWords.setBounds(10, 10+label_h+35, label_w, label_h);
    add(MatchWholeWords);

    find_next.setBounds(250, 10, 100, 20);
    add(find_next);
    cancel.setBounds(250, 40, 100, 20);
    add(cancel);
    int w = 400;
    int h = 200;
    setSize(w,h);
    Point center = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getCenterPoint();
    setLocation(center.x-w/2, center.y-h/2);
    setVisible(true);
}
 public static void main(String args[]){
  new FindDemo();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use Swing components instead of AWT components (`Label` → `JLabel`; `TextField` → `JTextField`, ...)
2. Don't use a null layout manager (`setLayout(null)`) and `setBounds()`. Examine [Using Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html).
3. Instead of `setSize(w, h)` use `pack()` method.

> full name is not displayed

Because you use `setBounds()` and null layout. `matchCase.setBounds(10, 10 + label_h + 10, label_w, label_h)` you set not enough space for `JCheckBox` because of that it shows with '...'.

For example your panel with a `GridBagLayout`:

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestFrame extends JFrame {

    JLabel l1;
    JCheckBox matchCase, MatchWholeWords;
    JTextField tf;
    JButton find_next, cancel;

    public TestFrame() {
        l1 = new JLabel("Find What: ");
        matchCase = new JCheckBox();
        matchCase.setText("Match Case ");
        MatchWholeWords = new JCheckBox("Match Whole Words ");
        tf = new JTextField(30);
        find_next = new JButton("Find Next");
        cancel = new JButton("Cancel");

        setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.insets = new Insets(5, 5, 5, 5);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
        add(l1, c);
        c.gridx++;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.weightx = 1;
        add(tf, c);
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.NONE;
        c.weightx = 0;
        c.gridx++;
        add(find_next, c);
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 1;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(matchCase, c);
        c.gridx++;
        c.gridx++;
        c.gridwidth = 1;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(cancel, c);
        c.gridy++;
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 2;
        add(MatchWholeWords, c);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestFrame();
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Re. layouts.  See also [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) and layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).